# MailServer forwarding policy issue

Tags: sendmail, mail-server, email-forwarding

**Description**:
We have a mailbox to which emails are forwarded from external system. Based on the mails events are generated.

Whenever a email is sent it is getting forwarded to another mail id.

But we are unable to understand what script is behind. The script reads the emails and forwards to one of the mails from the list. In /etc/aliases I see the below. But I want to know is how mails are first coming to either of the policies mentioned below.

> port-policy: "| /etc/smrsh/script.pl -u uei.opennms.org/xxx/OCI/SMTP/portViolationAlert"
>   storage-policy: "| /etc/smrsh/script.pl -u uei.opennms.org/xxx/OCI/SMTP/storageViolationAlert"
>   volume-policy: "| /etc/smrsh/script.pl -u uei.opennms.org/xxx/OCI/SMTP/volumeViolationAlert"